# Telnet reads double characters when running python server script

Tags: python, sockets, cmd, telnet

So I am new to python and I'm trying to learn some socket programming and the following script, when ran and connected to the server via telnet, returns me something like "hheelllloo wwoorrlldd" instead of letting me write "hello world" and then send the data. I've looked online and I've already tried to change the localecho setting in telnet and that didn't work either.

The servers script is:

```
import socket
import sys
import threading

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 10000))
sock.listen(1)

connections = []

def handler(c, a):

    global connections

    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        for connection in connections:
            connection.send(bytes(data))
        if not data:
            connections.remove(c)
            c.close()
            break

while True:
    c, a = sock.accept()
    conn_thread = threading.Thread(target = handler, args = (c, a))
    conn_thread.daemon = True
    conn_thread.start()
    connections.append(c)
```

The code when ran should return the sender the text he sent. I think mine does it character by character, without pressing enter to send and I don't know why. I might be wrong though.

Also, I'm running Windows 10, if this matters.

Comment: How does you client look? Is it a script or is it a standard telnet program?

Comment: @JohanL I basically just type in cmd telnet followed by the ip address and the port to which it should connect. Nothing more.

Comment: The issue is with the Windows telnet client. It is sending your characters one at a time to your server, which is then repeating them back, as it receives them, Also, the telnet client also seems to echo the characters to the console, even if localecho is off. I don't know why.